# No 32 development library error after install glibc-devel.i686

Tags: centos, gcc, glibc

I am trying to install gcc 4.9.0 on centOS 6.
During `./configure` there is an error coming up:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-   linux/4.4.7/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure: error: I suspect your system does not have 32-bit developement libraries (libc and headers). If you have them, rerun configure with --enable-multilib. If you do not have them, and want to build a 64-bit-only compiler, rerun configure with --disable-multilib.
```

I have searched for an answer and found out that this error should be resolved by installing the `glibc-devel.i686` package.

However, the same error persists even after I install it using `yum`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To be a tiny bit more explicit than @Miroslav answer:

<kbd>1</kbd> The dependencies

```
#64-bit (`x86_64`) C library and headers
yum install libgcc
yum install glibc-devel

# 32-bit (‘i386’) C library and headers
yum install libgcc.i686
yum install glibc-devel.i686
```

See all of them in [GCC Prerequesites](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html).

<kbd>2</kbd> Then compile with `--enable-multilib`

```
../configure --enable-languages=all --prefix=/usr/local/gcc --enable-multilib
```

---

## Edit.

**Side Note:** Don't compile in the same directory, as I can see `./configure` in your example. See [Installing GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC)

> Do not run ./configure, this is not supported, you need to run
> configure from outside the source directory

Answer (score 2):

I would say you need to install libgcc.i686