# Error compiling 64-bit on 32-bit machine with -m64

Tags: cross-compilation

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
g++ -m64 -g -Wall -DCPP -c -Wno-char-subscripts -o myprogram.oS64 myprogram.cpp
myprogram.cpp:1: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
make: [myprogram.oS64] Error 1 (ignored)
```

Here is my version of g++:

```
[root@VoIPserver8 VoipSim] 8 # g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i386-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --enable-plugin --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --with-cpu=generic --host=i386-redhat-linux
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Cross Compiling is only implemented using multilib, i.e. you can compile for different bit architectures, but it is impossible, since your   `i386-redhat-linux-g++` was built without multilib support.  See [gcc: Compile a 64-bit binary on 32-bit platform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582218/gcc-compile-a-64-bit-binary-on-32-bit-platform).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will see how to go about reinstalling g++ and gcc with multilib support.

Comment: The only way I know of is to install a 64 bit OS and install a multilib compiler from your repository.

Comment: There must be an alternate way, because we have another server with a 32-bit OS: `Linux serv 2.6.18-53.el5 #1 SMP Wed Oct 10 16:34:02 EDT 2007 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux` but it can compile 64 bit code when using the -m64 flag.

Comment: Here is the output of g++ -v on that server: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15768182/

Comment: I just checked my versions of gcc and g++ on my Gentoo box, and each contain ‘--enable-multilib‘,   To my knowledge, the only way to have a multilib compiler is a 64 bit OS.  Multiple versions are allowed via a chroot but not multiple architectures.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output should look similar to this:

```
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/gcc-4.9.3/work/gcc-4.9.3/configure --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.9.3 --includedir=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/include --datadir=/usr/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3 --mandir=/usr/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/man --infodir=/usr/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/info --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/include/g++-v4 --with-python-dir=/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/python --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --enable-obsolete --enable-secureplt --disable-werror --with-system-zlib --enable-nls --without-included-gettext --enable-checking=release --with-bugurl=https://bugs.gentoo.org/ --with-pkgversion='Gentoo 4.9.3 p1.5, pie-0.6.4' --enable-libstdcxx-time --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-multilib --with-multilib-list=m32,m64 --disable-altivec --disable-fixed-point --enable-targets=all --disable-libgcj --enable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --disable-libcilkrts --enable-lto --with-cloog --disable-isl-version-check --enable-libsanitizer
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.3 (Gentoo 4.9.3 p1.5, pie-0.6.4)
```

See also: [No 32 development library error after install glibc-devel.i686](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140280/no-32-development-library-error-after-install-glibc-devel-i686).  Notice that the answer there contains `--enable-multilib`

As a side note, I think you ought to try compiling on the server you say that compiles 64 bit code as neither contain `--enable-multilib`.  Even a prepackaged RedHat compiler that was multilib would report that it is multilib, and neither your question, or the pastebin contain the flag.

Comment: You were right. Apparently the 64-bit binary was being built on another machine. It just happened that the other machine mounted the folder on the 32-bit machine. Thank you very much for your help!